# Why is my code raising a TypeError exception?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

When I run the following code:

```
 while start == "yes":

    player1name = input("Player 1 what shall your character be called?")
    player2name = input("Player 2 what shall your character be called?")

    player1strength=print("Player 1,your strength score is :)", random.randint(1,7))
    player2strength=print("Player 2,your strength score is :)", random.randint(1,7))
    strengthdifference =(int(player1strength) - int(player2strength))
    if strengthdifference<0:
        strengthdifference=player2strength-player1strength
        strengthdifference=strengthdifference/5
        player1skill=int(input("Player 1,enter your skill score :)"))
        player2skill=int(input("Player 2,enter your skill score :)"))
        skilldifference=player1skill-player2skill
```

I'm getting this traceback:

```
File "C:\Computing\A453 Assessment\Task 3\main.py", line 18, in <module>
    strengthdifference =(int(player1strength) - int(player2strength))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix the error?

Comment: You don't want `player1strength = print(...)`. What you want is `player1strength = random.randint(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

The error says their `player1strength` or `player2strength` (or possibly both) are `None`, which `int()` can't take as a parameter.  It probably *is* both, since you are assigning the result of a call to `print` to each.

Maybe *it* does say something about *strength difference`, but since you haven't provided details, I can't respond to that.